# Why am I not getting firebase storage files url in my react app?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

In my React app, I've main three functionality which is connected to firebase. firebase auth, real-time chat, and this third one require firebase storage. I want to upload images with chat messages.
when I try to upload images, the console gives me this error when I try to `console.log(url)` 
I want to get that downloaded image url and store it in my firestore database and then use that url inside my `Message.js` component.
[image: console shows me this error]

My Chat.js component

```
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);
  const [assets, setAssets] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (channelId) {
      db.collection("channels")
        .doc(channelId)
        .collection("messages")
        .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
          setMessages(snapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()));
        });
    }
  }, [channelId]);

  const sendMessage = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const uploadTask = storage.ref(`assets_discord/${assets.name}`).put(assets);
    uploadTask.on("state_changed", () => { 
      storage
        .ref("assetsdiscord")
        .child(assets.name)
        .getDownloadURL()
        .then((url) => {
          db.collection("assetUrl").add({
            imgUrl: url,
          });
          console.log(url);
          setAssets(null);
        });
      });
      db.collection("channels").doc(channelId).collection("messages").add({
        user: user,
        message: input,
        timestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      });
      
    setInput("");
  };

  const hideInput = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setShowInput(!showInput);
  };

  return (
    <div className="chat">
      {channelId ? (
        <>
          <ChatHeader channelName={channelName} />
          <div className="chat__messages">
            {messages.map((message) => (
              <Message
                user={message.user}
                message={message.message}
                timestamp={message.timestamp}
                assetUrl={message.imgUrl}
              />
            ))}
          </div>
          <div className="chat__input">
            {showInput ? (
              <>
                <form action="#">
                  <label htmlFor="imgFiles" className="upload__img">
                    <AddCircle fontSize="large" />
                  </label>
                  <input
                    type="file"
                    id="imgFiles"
                    className="hidden"
                    accept="image/*"
                    onChange={(e) => {
                      if (e.target.files[0]) {
                        setAssets(e.target.files[0]);
                      }
                    }}
                  />
                  <input
                    disabled={!channelId}
                    value={input}
                    onChange={(e) => setInput(e.target.value)}
                    type="text"
                    placeholder={`Send Message to #${channelName}`}
                  />
                  <button
                    onClick={sendMessage}
                    className="chat__inputButton"
                    type="Submit"
                  >
                    Send Message
                  </button>
                  <button onClick={hideInput}>Hide</button>
                </form>
              </>
            ) : (
              <p
                onClick={() => setShowInput(!showInput)}
                className="show__input"
              >
                Show
              </p>
            )}
          </div>
        </>
      ) : (
        <>
          <div className="chat__selectRoom">
            <ArrowLeftIcon
              style={{ fontSize: "30px" }}
              className="arrow__left"
            />
            <h3>Select Any Room to get Started</h3>
          </div>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
```

Message Component

```
const Message = ({ user, timestamp, message, assetUrl }) => {
  // console.log(assetUrl);
  return (
    <div className="message">
      <Avatar src={user.photo} />
      <div className="message__info">
        <h4>
          {user.displayName}
          <span className="message__timestamp">
            {new Date(timestamp?.toDate()).toUTCString()}
          </span>
        </h4>
        <p>{message}</p>
        {/*
         <ImageUpload assetUrl={assetUrl} /> 
       */}
        <img src={assetUrl} alt="dummy" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

firebase sequrity rules

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

[Link to live website](https://discord-clone-jv.netlify.app/)

Comment: Check the address for the file if it is wrong. It is for sure that the file does not exist, check what url you are fetching from the api.

Comment: Yes it's saying file doesn't exist when I click on the firebase api URL, the url that I'm fetching api is also hosted on firebase but I am using netlify link for production. You are saying I should check my firebase url?

Comment: Yes, check the url you are getting and download the file manually. At least you can know where is the problem, in firebase rules or in your code.

Comment: I visited the console error url but it shows me object this object: 
{
"error": {
"code": 403,
"message": "Permission denied. Could not perform this operation"
}
}
I don't understand what's wrong?

Comment: We got it, the problem is in the firebase rules. Google provides security rules by which we can control people to access our firebase storage. I am posting an answer, please check it.

Answer (score 3):

Go to the firebase console then select the project you are working on then go to storage then rules.

[image]

If you are using firestore or database then check the rules. Another problem can be that you have not added the SHA of your project. We are allowing everyone to change the storage means public access.

In your case, as you commented, the problem can be security access.
[Here is a link to google documenations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics?authuser=0#cloud-firestore)

I would suggest you read documentation before using any platforms like Amazon AWS, firebase, or any type of API.

**Another CHeck**  - Check the address of the files, I rechecked the error. Your security rules are correct, I think you should use some samples from documentations.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Vijay, I changed the rules for storage but now I upload the image it shows error code 404 instead 403. Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: Object 'assetsdiscord/Screenshot (226).png' does not exist. (storage/object-not-found)
{
  "error": {
    "code": 404,
    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",
    "status": "GET_OBJECT"
  }
}

Comment: I checked the link of the api of image it goes like this: https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/instagram-clone-jv.appspot.com/o/assetsDiscord%2FScreenshot%20(226).png?alt=media&token=6ebf5e8a-aad3-4c9c-ab0f-540d751b7847

Comment: Maybe there's a problem in my react app?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your app and the firebase server, you should calm and patient. See it is saying that the object not found (I don't know javascript as I am an android developer), but in java it means that the StorageReferece is not initialized. According to the error there can be two mistakes either the object has some problem and the second is the location of the file (files you want to upload or where you want to upload) is incorrect. Be patient and see step by step, where is the mistake.

Comment: Thanks Vijay for all your help and I will take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

When you are referring to upload you are using 'assets_discord' but when you want to get the URL you are referring to 'assetsdiscord'